# XSLT. I need to preprocess XML into other XML before processing via XSLT into HTML. How is this done?

Tags: xml, xslt, preprocessor

Good day,

My XSLT transforms XLM pages into HTML pages. Now I am stuck with a problem, that seems not trivial to me. I would appreciate a pointer into the right direction.

I want to reduce the number of lines I have to write in my original XML files. What I want, is something like a XSLT preprocessor, translating some XML tags into a group of other XML tags, before XSLT processes them. If at all possible, I want to keep the replaced as well as the replacing lines in the same XML document (so, no include-file-style solutions).

Example:

Oftentimes, my XML files contain repetitive multiple lines, e.g. the following simplified snippet:

```
<img>
        <url>a_midi.jpg</url>
</img>
<img>
        <url>b_midi.jpg</url>
</img>
<img>
        <url>c_midi.jpg</url>
</img>
```

It would be great, if I could include these multiple lines into a macro tag, placed somewhere near the beginning of the XML file, like this:

```
<macro id="name_a">
        <img>
                <url>a_midi.jpg</url>
        </img>
        <img>
                <url>b_midi.jpg</url>
        </img>
        <img>
                <url>c_midi.jpg</url>
        </img>
</macro>
```

Instead of repeating the initial lines over and over again at various places, I'd just use something like:

```
 <use_macro id="name_a"/>
```

Now, I certainly can instruct the XSLT to process the template *macro* matching the name "name_a", when it encounters the *use_macro* tag.

However, this is not what I want. The reason is, that above *img* tags are themselves contained in another surrounding tag, say *multi_img*. The XSLT processing this  tag considers a lot of other tags contained in itself, which dictate how exactly the XML is transformed into HTML (and sometimes the *img* tags even need to be processed multiple times in different manners.)

Hence, what I am looking for, is a way to

(1) first transform the XML *use_macro* into the XML contained in the *macro* tag;

(2) and then process the resulting XML with XSLT as if there was no *use_macro* tag at all in the first place.

Possibly the solution is obvious and I am just overworked, but I can't find what I need (even not after spending some time with Jeni Tennison's "XSLT and XPath / On the edge").

I appreciate pointers (also to the appropriate chapter in Tennison's book), or just the statement "it can not be done". Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Herb

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have to do two steps. 
The obvious and easiest solution may be to do generate a temporary xml file. Which only have the `use_macro` extended.  Than call the original xslt for this temp file.

Doing this two steps  with only one xlst processor call depend on xslt version.

With xslt-1.0 you need to use a extension like `node-set()`.
As first step generate a variable with the complete xml file but `use_macro` extended.
Than apply the  original XLST whith something like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates  select="exsl:node-set($xml_whith_use_macro_extended)/*" />
```

For xsltpoc this will do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
                    >
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="extend">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="extend"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="macro"  mode="extend" />
    <xsl:template match="use_macro"  mode="extend" >
        <xsl:copy-of select="//macro[@id = current()/@id]" />
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="xml_whith_use_macro_extended"  >
        <xsl:apply-templates mode ="extend" select="/*" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="exsl:node-set($xml_whith_use_macro_extended)/*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- other temlates -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```